# adding more than two button on the navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am trying this but it does not work.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // create a toolbar where we can place some buttons
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 45)];
    [toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    // create an array for the buttons
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

    // create a standard save button
    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
        target:self
        action:@selector(saveAction:)];
    saveButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:saveButton];
    [saveButton release];

    // create a spacer between the buttons
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
        target:nil
        action:nil];
    [buttons addObject:spacer];
    [spacer release];

    // create a standard delete button with the trash icon
    UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
        target:self
        action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
    deleteButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:deleteButton];
    [deleteButton release];

    // put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
    [toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
    [buttons release];

    // place the toolbar into the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithCustomView:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: There are several similar questions at StackOverflow. Take a look at [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=navigation+bar+multiple+items).

Comment: I know but this code is not working that's way ask ?

Comment: this is a cocoa-touch question. so please keep the tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
[toolbar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

// create an array for the buttons
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

// create a standard save button
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
saveButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:saveButton];
[saveButton release];

// create a standard delete button with the trash icon
UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
deleteButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:deleteButton];
[deleteButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *addbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
addbutton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:addbutton];
[addbutton release];

UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                              target:self
                              action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
editButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:editButton];
[editButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
doneButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:doneButton];
[doneButton release];

// put the buttons in the toolbar and release them
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];

// place the toolbar into the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

**Try this code snippet**

And In  AppDelegate.h file you declare this

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

And AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: it's not working friend.I just want simply add the button on the navigationbar .For doing this i just dregs navigationbar on the and drop on the view .Then after word i add this code in .m file

Comment: I have posted a code snippet. In that i have added 5 buttons. Have a look at this. :)

Comment: In ViewController class where-ever you want place.

Answer (score 50):

with iOS 5 you can add more buttons

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uibarbuttonInstance1, uibarbuttonInstance2, nil];
```

same for right buttons

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uibarbuttonInstance1, uibarbuttonInstance2, nil];
```

Comment: Yes..definitely saved a lot of time... +1

Answer (score 2):

I think i'm giving u my code this will solve ur problem ...

```
-(void) initializeNavigationalBar {

self.navigationItem.title  = @"What Ever");

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57/255) green:(57/255) blue:(57/255) alpha:1];
UIBarButtonItem *optionBtn; 
optionBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
             initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]
             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
             target:self 
             action:@selector(LoadOption:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = optionBtn;

// create a toolbar to have two buttons in the right
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44.01)];
// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self 
                                action:@selector(decrement:)];

[buttons addObject:rightBtn];
[previousBtn release];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self 
                            action:@selector(increment:)];
[buttons addObject:leftBtn];
[nextBtn release];
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
tools.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57/255) green:(57/255) blue:(57/255) alpha:1];
[buttons release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```

}

Enjoy...

Comment: Thanks for code. But you are doing an integer division, so button is always black. Just change 255 by 255.0 and would be a float division.

Answer (score 0):

this code work well.just now i check your code. Build-->clean all targets and then check

Comment: hello friend .Can I add segment in the place of button on navigationbar

Comment: @user6271 Yeah  sure to add uisegmentedcontrol on navigation bar

Comment: How can i replace the segment button1 with other segment button2 on click of segment button1 .