# Add Two or more buttons on Navigationbar

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding more than two button on the navigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249416/adding-more-than-two-button-on-the-navigationbar)

**How can add two more buttons on navaigationbar?**. My codes are follows.if i am using rightBarButtonItem methods there is no problem with items.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barPrint = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tool_print.png"]
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(printAttach:)];
        UISwitch *OnOff = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        UIBarButtonItem *barOnOff = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:OnOff];

        //[onoff1 addTarget: self action: @selector(flip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barOnOff, barPrint, nil];
        [OnOff release];
```

Comment: Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];`

Comment: code is fine, but question is not clear... are you getting 2 items in the bar?

Comment: Error is coming at runtime.. if i only display one item then it is ok, is  there any problem with my code?..I have doubt about my barPrint button.

Comment: I did it. for that i used the following link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249416/adding-more-than-two-button-on-the-navigationbar

Thankyou for ur comment

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
 [iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```