# UINavigationItem: Add one more button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationitem

[image]

How can I add new button in navigationItem? Say I need to add it near right button.

Code used for left right.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_cancelButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_shareButton];
```

How can I add one more button?

Comment: Refer the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249416/adding-more-than-two-button-on-the-navigationbar)

Comment: @Jyotishree thanks...let me try in that way.

Comment: add buttons to  UIView and then add that view to as right bar buttonitem.

Comment: @BobApple, tried..no success....any sample please...

Comment: oky let me post the detail answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are Different Approach to add more then one Buttons on right side of navigationcontroller.one of the Simplist way is given  below

```
 UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];

UIButton *exampleButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
exampleButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2, 30, 40);
[exampleButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(FirstMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[exampleButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonView addSubview:exampleButton1];


UIButton *exampleButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
exampleButton2.frame = CGRectMake(70, 2, 30, 40);
[exampleButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(Second method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[exampleButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[buttonView addSubview:exampleButton2];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView];
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can add more buttons

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uibarbuttonInstance1, uibarbuttonInstance2, nil];
```

same for right buttons

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uibarbuttonInstance1, uibarbuttonInstance2, nil];
```

Comment: I tried this before and now...got crash :   -[UIButton isSystemItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa68b840'

Comment: add UIBarButton not UIbutton

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor, though it's too late. I had the same problem as yours. I was actually putting in UIImage instead of UIBarButton into the array.

Answer (score 2):

**Middle Button**

```
UIButton *btnShow = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34)];
    btnShow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.411 alpha:1.000];
    [btnShow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnShow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = btnShow;
```

**Right Bar Button**

```
 UIButton *tempButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tempButton1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34)];
    tempButton1.tag = 0;
    [tempButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [tempButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempButton1]];
```

**Left Bar button**

```
UIButton *tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tempButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 34, 34)];
[tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempButton]
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: in TitleView you have placed Text or what ???? Okay... If so... you need both text and button or in the text itself acts as button

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *tempArray2= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.shareBtn,self.gameCenterBtn,nil];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=tempArray2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    flex.width = 20;
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mac-gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *bar1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];

    UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];
    [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mac-gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *bar2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn2];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:bar1,flex,bar2, nil];
```