# Navigation Styling throughout app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

is there a way to implement the below code for the styling of my navigation bar in ViewDidLoad or globally somehow, instead of pasting in every VC? Thanks.

```
// Navagation styling
    viewController.title = @"NAV TITLE";
    [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gibson-Light" size:20.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                      target:viewController
                                                                      action:nil];

    rightBarButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_cog"];
    rightBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
```

Comment: Create UIViewController subclass, paste above code in it and extend it to all other view controller.

Comment: Its better to create Category and add -(void)addRightButtonItem; method to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a BaseViewController and put the above code in it and extend all your controllers from the BaseViewController.

Do like this:

Create an Objective-C class BaseViewController.h and .m

**In BaseViewController.h**

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *_title;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil title:(NSString *)navTitle;    

@end
```

**In BaseViewController.m**

```
@implementation BaseViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil title:(NSString *)navTitle
{
    _title = navTitle;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = _title;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Gibson-Light" size:20.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:viewController
                                                                  action:nil];
    rightBarButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_cog"];
    rightBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
}

@end
```

Now you can create your view controller and extend it from BaseViewController instead if UIViewController.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great this along with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249416/adding-more-than-two-button-on-the-navigationbar helped me to add element to right navigationitems based on success or failure of condition with minimum codes.